# FileZilla single file transfer speed slowed down (it was fast before)

Tags: 20.04, ssh, files, transfer

I have a server from where I download big files with the following specs:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- Kernel: 5.4.0-67-generic
- CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1275 v5 @ 3.60GHz
- RAM: 4x16GB DDR4
- Storage: 500GB SSD
- Speedtest: Download: 901.30 Mbit/s // Upload: 768.25 Mbit/s

---

Using SSH/SFTP

The problem I encounter is that for a few months the transfer speed over single files have slowed down.

I usually download the backups from the server once a week or so, which are 3-5 GB tar files.

For the first 4 months I had the file transfer from the server to my PC around 20-25 MB/s.
Now in the last 2 months the file transfer speed dropped to ~1.5MB/s (stays between 1.4 - 1.6 MB/s).
I usually download with my PC from Steam with 70-80MB/s, so bandwidth issues wouldn't be a problem.

Haven't done anything on server to the configs, just regular apt-get update & apt-get upgrade

I once had a 30GB file to transfer, and had to wait for around 6 hours.

I've tried to make the file available to transfer via http, but the same 1.5MB/s speed.

I have also other servers with same OS but different kernels, but the problem is the same there, transfering files are limited to 1.5MB/s (and haven't been before - when I installed them and transferred what I needed on them).

I tried using rsync and tar cf - * | pv | netcat ip 7000

Using netcat and pv between the servers showed up to 113MiB/s using this method:

- On destination server: `nc -ulp 5000 > /dev/null`
- On source server: `pv < /dev/zero | nc -u listener-ip-address 5000`

The same netcat and pv between the server which had the big files and my PC using Ubuntu from witin Windows got me 111MiB/s

All transfers are now slow at 1.5MB/s even between the servers and that's pretty annoying, because I can transfer 10 different files and they would all transfer at 1.5MB/s, but if it is only one file, the speed wouldn't increase.

Also disabled firewall for every machine and still same issue.

It may be the IPS but not sure, I think it has something to do with some config which got overwritten and that limits the speed and I don't know which and where would that be.

The ping between PC and the server which has the big files: 42-43ms

The ping between the servers: 36-37ms

The strange thing is that using FileZila/WinSCP on any server limits the transfer speed / file to 1.5MB/s

Also tried FTP between PC and server.

My PC SpeedTest: Download: 750.00 Mbit/s // Upload: 531.99 Mbit/s

Write speeds on servers using:
`hdparm -Tt /dev/sda`

On the one with the big files:

```
/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   33094 MB in  1.99 seconds = 16664.27 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1608 MB in  3.00 seconds = 535.49 MB/sec
```

On the other one where I tried to copy/transfer the file:

```
/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   39006 MB in  2.00 seconds = 19533.29 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1600 MB in  3.00 seconds = 532.77 MB/sec
```

Comment: Related: [Why is FileZilla SFTP file transfer max capped at 1.3MiB/sec instead of saturating available bandwidth?](https://serverfault.com/q/694062/168875)

Comment: Yeah, setting the process to high/realtime did nothing. The CPU is under 10% usage on all cores both on server and on PC.
It's weird because I used to have about 22MB/s download from server and about 15MB/s upload, but now it's limited to 1.5
The more weird thing is that I can upload like 5-10 files but all have the same speed..
And during the transfer, the speedtest showed plenty of bandwidth

Comment: Same issue. 250-300kBs per file max, but i can upload 30-40 files at that speed .... problem is my file is 50gb xD

Comment: Update: issue resolved itself on its own... LOL